# How can I get trace of my linq query (using linqtotwitter on windows 8 app in c# and xaml)

Tags: linq, logging, microsoft-metro, trace

I'm developping a Windows 8 metro app using linqtotwitter.

I need to get a trace of my linq queries in my log file but I searched and didn't find hox can I do this.
Everything that I read speak about linq to sql, with a database, I don't have a database.
I get information by querying the Twitter API via linqtotwitter.

How can I get a trace of my query?

My code:

```
User usersResponse = new User();

        usersResponse = (from user in twitterCtxProp.User
                         where user.Type == UserType.Lookup &&
                          user.ScreenName == name
                         select user).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: [Twitterizer](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer) is best library. I have used that.

Answer (score 0):

It's open source, so check the source to see if the developer used Systems.Diagnostics trace, nlogger or some other logging framework. If so with some web.config edits you can view the trace.  If he used outputdebugstring, you can use debugview http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx to see the trace.

If he didn't instrument the library for trace, (not all developers buy into the idea of trace), then you'd want to pick your favorite library and add some trace commands.

And finally, if you are interested in the final result (but not how the library go there) use fiddler to see what goes across the wire to twitter: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/